# adjustment of footer in website

Tags: html, css

I m web designer and getting problem in adjustment of footer.
I need footer should be fixed at specific height and it will get down if content incresed otherwise it will be at same position please help me ....

Thanks
Mayur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to remain at the bottom of the window, try this:

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: True, but IE 6 is 8.9% of the market, and most of those computers are workstations in large companies or people only using IE6 temporarily to use an IE6-only application. I gave the Bird to IE 6 long, long ago.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be absolutely cross-browser-compatible try this one: [cssstickyfooter.com](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This css snippet should do the trick:

```
#footer{  
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: maybe bottom: -(height of footer)px would be better. also you must set teh content to position:relative for this to work